# how do you open a PDF at a specific page from the command line? (OSX or Linux)

Tags: macos, pdf, command-line

I want to open a PDF document at a specific page from the command line, sort of like `vim +n [file]`. Is there any way to do that in OSX, with any PDF reader program?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with [Evince](http://projects.gnome.org/evince/) using the `-p` or `--page-label=PAGE` command line argument like so:

```
evince -p 5 foo.pdf
```

Answer (score 7):

I kept getting errors from Julio's answer. With the current Version 1.4.6 (80) of Skim and OSX Mountain Lion (10.8.5), the following code worked for me. I think the issue might be that pageNum has to be treated as an integer, but it gets parsed in as a string. This code assumes you have Skim installed.

gotopage.scpt:

```
on run argv
    set fileName to (item 1 of argv)
    set pageNum to (item 2 of argv) as integer

    tell application "Skim"
        open fileName
        tell document 1 to go to page pageNum
        activate
    end tell
end run
```

Skim still needs an absolute filename. So you would run it with the same command mentioned in Julio's answer. `osascript gotopage.scpt "/full/path/to/doc/mydoc.pdf" 99`

Answer (score 6):

The following method works with Skim, an open-source replacement for Preview.app. First, download [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/), then save the following code on a text file and name it "gotopage.scpt":

```
on run argv
    tell application "Skim"
        activate
        open (item 1 of argv)

        tell document 1
            go to page index (item 2 of argv)
        end tell

    end tell
end run
```

You can now tell Skim to open a certain PDF and go to page 99 by writing this on the terminal:

```
osascript gotopage.scpt "/full/path/to/doc/mydoc.pdf" 99
```

You might want to wrap the above line into an sh script of your own. Also note that the path to the PDF must be absolute, otherwise Skim won't find the file.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this will help you: 
http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf

I found an arg page=pagenum on page 5 in this pdf that might be useful! I haven't tested it though!

**EDIT:**

I just tested it on Windows (unfortunately I don't have Linux) and it works. On windows it's:

```
<path to Acrobat Reader.exe> /A "page=2" somePDFFile.pdf
```

I guess it's something similar in Linux or OSX.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you can open a PDF file (say, `file.pdf`) to a certain page (say, page `23`) using [**Okular**](https://okular.kde.org/), [**mupdf**](https://mupdf.com/), [**qpdfview**](https://launchpad.net/qpdfview), or [**gv**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gv/), with the respective commands:

```
 okular -p 23 file.pdf

 mupdf file.pdf 23

 qpdfview file.pdf#23

 gv -page=23 file.pdf
```

Answer (score -1):

No. Command line switches are specific to each program.

Answer (score -3):

```
open -a Preview someFile.pdf
```

Comment: How can he open the PDF at a specific page, though?