# how to open a pdf file from Matlab in specific page

Tags: linux, matlab, pdf

I want to open a PDF file from Matlab in specific page. I used command `web`:

```
web('fille:///D:\file.pdf#page=3')
```

but the PDF does not open in page 3, but it opens on page 1. Is there a solution?

Comment: Does this command really require `fille`?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to perform this using the `web` command (it seems that not all the web engines support this `PDF` feature), but through a command ([system](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) function) this can be easily achieved.

Under Windows:

```
system('"C:\Path\To\AcroRd32.exe" /A "page=3" "C:\Path\To\file.pdf"');
```

Under Linux with [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince) (more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057595/how-do-you-open-a-pdf-at-a-specific-page-from-the-command-line-osx-or-linux)):

```
system('evince -p 3 /path/to/file.pdf');
```