# Is there a way to open a pdf at specific page using adobe acrobat programatically on mac?

Tags: python, html, pdf, adobe, acrobat

Is it possible to open a pdf at a specific page programmatically in adobe acrobat on a Mac using python or an html link?

The method described on [this page](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html) does its job but only opens the file in the browser, e.g.,:

```html
<A HREF="assets/paper3.2004_dehaene_011810_975095.pdf#page=4">link</A>
```

I have tried adding "adobe" / "acrobat" / "adobeacrobat" in front of the link, like this:

```html
<A HREF="adobe://assets/paper3.2004_dehaene_011810_975095.pdf#page=4">link</A>
```

But none of them have worked.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`HREF="assets/paper3.2004_dehaene_011810_975095.pdf#page=4"`

is a Browser plug-in ***URL with #fragment*** command, thus can only work with browsers that have a PDF compatible plug-in such as provided by Adobe Acrobat Reader or similar enabled plug-in such as native Chromium/Edge or Firefox PDF.js .*and see footnote [to my absolute amazement SumatraPDF in Safari !]

For Command line use Adobe Acrobat executable uses an /Action syntax (emulated by TrackerX-change and Foxit etc) so the above command would be similar to

`PDFapplication /A "page=4" assets/paper3.2004_dehaene_011810_975095.pdf`

Thus on Windows (it will be much the same in other OS systems)

"c:/Path to /AcroRd32" /A "page=4" assets/paper3.2004_dehaene_011810_975095.pdf

Result

[image]

However your question as asked in Adobe forum did not suggest that was Mac method of launching the app.
https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/python-mac-open-pdf-file-to-specific-page-and-section/m-p/12538452

Thus I would possibly best to use something like a Skim/Preview solution see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19823820/10802527 and other comments.

- [Footnote] Out of interest I tried opening the sample reference in Windows Safari (unsupported)

And was most surprised to see a familiar SumatraPDF toolbar (browser retired but functional in Windows 11) That is a bonus for me !

[image]